# How do i fix the issue of user input printing on the next line

Tags: java

from my code bellow i find that the input for vehicle make and model prints on a separate line how can i avoid this. I have attached a copy of the output also

```
System.out.print("Enter Hire Length (in days):");
int hLength = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
System.out.println("Enter Vehicle Make and Model:");
makeMod = input.nextLine();     
System.out.print("Enter Vehicle registration No:");
regNum = input.nextLine();
```

Output

```
Enter Hire Length (in days):9
Enter Vehicle Make and Model: <<< this is where the Issue is Mazda 3 should be after here
Mazda 3                       <<< Not here
Enter Vehicle registration No:YJZ 561
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change the println to print in line #3

```
System.out.print("Enter Vehicle Make and Model:");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `System.out.print()` when you want the cursor to stay on the current line on which the output was printed to. `System.out.println()` appends a newline character on the end of the output it just printed which is why the cursor will now be on the next line when you go to enter your values.

Answer (score 0):

```
 System.out.println("Enter Vehicle Make and Model:");
```

Because of this `println()` always prints in new line. use `print()` as same as you already use in other two.

Comment: it would be more appropriate to say " println() terminates the CURRENT line by writing the line separator string."

Answer (score 0):

Remove bellow statement

```
System.out.println("Enter Vehicle Make and Model:");
```

& Put like this
    System.out.print("Enter Vehicle Make and Model:");

there is difference between println & print